# C - char** not printing correctly after being returned from function

Tags: c

I am trying to return a char** from a function to main so I can do stuff with it, but when I print it out it gives me random characters. I'm at a loss.

main VV

```
// ./main < data/filelist.txt

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hist.h"

int main(){

    int count = 0;
    int i;
    char** files = read(&count);
    displayList(files, count);

    char** array = splitFiles(files, count);
        printf("IN MAIN: array[0] - %s\n", array[0]);       
        Histogram* p; 
        printf("here\n");
        int histArrayCount = calcHistogram(&array[0], &count, &p);
        printf("here\n");
        displayHistogram(p, histArrayCount);
        printf("here\n");
}
```

hist.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hist.h"

int calcHistogram (char** a, int* count, Histogram** q) {

    int i, k;
    int j = 0;
    int histArrayCount = 0;

    Histogram* p = (Histogram*)malloc((*count) * sizeof(Histogram));
    for (k = 0; k < *count; k++) {
        p[k].num =  "1";
        p[k].freq = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= *count; i++) {
        while ((strcmp(p[j].num, "1") != 0) && (strcmp(p[j].num, a[i]) != 0)) {
            j++;
        }
        if (strcmp(p[j].num, "1") == 0) {
            p[j].num = a[i];
            p[j].freq = 1;
            histArrayCount++;
        }
        else if ((strcmp(p[j].num, a[i]) == 0)) {
            p[j].freq += 1;
        }
        else {
            printf("ERROR\n");
        }
        j = 0;
    }

    *q = p;

    return histArrayCount;
}

void displayHistogram (Histogram* p, int histArrayCount) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < histArrayCount - 1; i++) {
        printf("value %s: freq %d\n", p[i].num, p[i].freq);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

char** splitFiles(char** files, int count) {
        int i;
        char** array = (char**)malloc((count)*sizeof(char*)); 
        FILE* fp;
        int c = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                char buff[255];
                fp =  fopen(files[i], "r");

                array[i] = fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp);
                printf("%d : %s\n", i, buff);
        }

        printf("array[0] = %s\n", array[0]);
        return array;
}

void displayList(char** a, int c) { 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        printf("File %d: %s\n", i, a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


char** read(int* c){
    int count = 0;
    int i;

    char** a = (char**)malloc(100*sizeof(char*));

    for (i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
        a[count] = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
        count++;
    }

    count = 0;

    int endOfFile = scanf("%s", a[count]);

    while (endOfFile != EOF) {
            count++;
            endOfFile = scanf("%s", a[count]);
    }

    *c = count;
    return a;
}
```

When I print the array at index 0 in here it gives me what is actually there, but when I do the same thing in main it does not. It gives me three random characters.

hist.h

```
typedef struct Histogram {
    char* num;
    int freq;
} Histogram;

char** read(int* c);
void displayList(char** a, int c);
int calcHistogram (char** a, int* c, Histogram** p);
void displayHistogram (Histogram* a, int histArrayCount);
char** splitFiles (char** files, int count);
```

Comment: Standard common error. `array[i] = fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp);`. That stores `buff` which is then returned to the caller. But `buff` is a local variable and is not valid after the function returns. In fact, `buff` is scoped only to the `for` loop and is invalid as soon as that loop completes.

Comment: To add to the previous comment - think about `array` as an array of strings. You only allocated memory for this array's elements (which are just addresses, each is an address of a string). Now you have to allocate (using `malloc` if you want to use them outside of this function) a memory for each of these strings too.

Comment: A tip is to use `gdb` and `valgrind` to detect bugs

Comment: BTW, you should probably avoid defining your own functions with the same names as POSIX and C standard functions like `read()`.